# Insertion on a hash table

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm trying to write a program that creates a hash_table that handles collision with chained lists .The  chained list will be made of a structure made of 2 char.
I want to insert this type of structure at the start of the linked list, but i keep getting seg fault on a line and i can't understand why.
Here is my code:

```
typedef struct celula       //this is the chained list structure
{
    struct celula *urm;
    void *info;
} TCelulaG, *TLG;

typedef struct  //this is the hash_table structure      
{
    size_t M;
    TLG * v;
} TD;

typedef struct   // the structure that should be inserted
{
    char *key;
    char *value;
} TDate;
```

I have a hash function and an initialization function(sets every parameter of the table null ) that work well.

Now the insertion function:

```
int put(TDate element, TD * hash_table,size_t M)    
{
    TLG it,aux,ant;                     
    size_t h=hash(element.key,M);   
    it=(TLG)malloc(sizeof(TCelulaG));           
    it= hash_table->v[h];   
    it->info=(TDate*)malloc(sizeof(TDate));   //this is the line that causes the segfault

    it = hash_table->v[h];
    if(it==NULL)                        
    {
        ((TDate*)((it)->info))->key=element.key;
        ((TDate*)((it)->info))->value=element.value;
        it->urm=hash_table->v[h];
        hash_table->v[h]=it;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure `it` is not null

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `it` is not null.

Why do you allocate to `it` and then follow that with an assignment from `hash-table->v[h]`. It is likely that `hash_table->v[h]` is null and hence the segfault. Check for `it` before assigning to `it->info`.